# Formula for a square between two points?

Tags: geometry

Given two points $P$ and $Q$, it is easy to define the line segment between them. It is the set of points:

$$\{t P + (1-t) Q | t\in[0,1]\}$$

Is there a similar formula for the square in $\mathbb{R}^2$, having $P$ and $Q$ as opposite corners?

This will probably require two parameters, e.g.:

$$\{t P +  uQ | t\in[...], u\in[...]\}$$

But what range should be taken for $t$ and $u$?

Comment: I can think of several rectangles that might fit the description provided in your posting, not all of which are squares. Are you looking for (a) a square whose *diagonal* is the line segment between $P$ and $Q$, (b) a square whose *baseline* is the line segment $PQ$ (and which might protrude either above or below the baseline), or (c) a rectangle whose sides are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes?

Comment: I meant that $P$ and $Q$ are opposite corners, i.e., option (a).

Answer (score 4):

It won't be quite that simple. Consider $P=(0,0)$ and $Q=(1,1)$, no combination of the form $tP+uQ$ will give e.g. $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Find a coordinate transform $A$ that maps the vector $PQ$ to $(1,1)$. In this coordinate system, the square is given by

$$\{(t,u) \>|\> t,u\in[0,1]\}$$

Apply the inverse transform to get the equivalent representation in $\mathbb{R}^2$. As shown by @Henrik, though, for general points $P,Q$ this representation will not have the simple form from your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you know is that $P$ and $Q$ are tow opposite corners. Hence $PQ$ is a diagonal of the square.

Let's call $C$ and $D$ the remaining corners.

Then $\vec{ CD}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{PQ}$.

Moreover, you have $2\vec{PC}=\vec{PQ}+\vec{DC}$ and $2\vec{PD}=\vec{PQ}-\vec{DC}$

It is easy to find $C$ and $D$.

From there you have easily the mapping of your square with the basis of $\vec{PC}$ and $\vec{PD}$.